# Fixed Width and Height Text Container with Prev/Next Button

Tags: javascript, css, jpanel, scrollbar, carousel

I'm want to create a text container with fixed width and height like it's shown in the image.

This is an example how the box should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E0QR.jpg

I've tried the scrollbar box didn't work.

Example of the code used:

CSS Code:

```css
.box{
 direction:rtl;
    position:absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
    border: solid #000 2px;
}
.box-text {
 text-align:left;
 direction:ltr;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    color: #0000;
}
```

```html
HTML Code

<div class="box"> 
 <div class="box-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eleifend hendrerit magna, ac tristique nulla vestibulum id. Aenean aliquam vehicula nunc sit amet convallis. Mauris sit amet lectus a metus accumsan dignissim. Integer pharetra quam nec lectus mattis lobortis. Aliquam id risus vel ante ornare rhoncus ac quis lacus. Duis dignissim urna sed leo dictum fermentum. Vivamus id orci odio, in congue quam.

Mauris adipiscing justo nec dui vulputate vel dapibus urna fermentum. Aliquam dictum erat at urna molestie consectetur ut quis justo. Aliquam eu est mauris, ac condimentum erat. Aliquam pellentesque sem cursus quam feugiat at dignissim sem bibendum. Phasellus convallis commodo justo, dapibus egestas nisl ultricies non. Ut dui mauris, blandit ac tincidunt quis, interdum eget erat. Fusce nisi quam, tincidunt sed blandit eget, euismod eu felis. Sed consequat ligula id lacus fringilla quis mollis leo commodo. Morbi quis elementum diam. Vestibulum ultrices nunc nec nisl imperdiet molestie. Maecenas rutrum viverra dignissim. Nulla et orci ut nisl volutpat eleifend. Donec scelerisque elit ac arcu iaculis luctus.

Donec orci lectus, bibendum quis egestas vitae, cursus fringilla tellus. Cras at ipsum augue. Ut ornare eleifend volutpat. Morbi tristique sapien sed ipsum sodales non pharetra tellus porttitor. Aenean justo mi, tincidunt sit amet aliquam vitae, ornare ac libero. Donec faucibus ultrices augue non cursus. Pellentesque a ipsum eros, a rhoncus arcu. Mauris massa purus, tempus ultrices fermentum vel, sagittis id eros. Nam id massa dapibus mauris convallis imperdiet. Nullam erat dui, aliquet eu dignissim vel, convallis vitae enim. Quisque vel nulla dolor, nec mollis tortor. Phasellus fermentum velit eu ante pharetra interdum.

Aliquam pharetra, urna sit amet tincidunt ullamcorper, felis lectus posuere dui, ut bibendum lectus mi quis mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur volutpat accumsan urna a aliquam. Ut quis tellus at quam ornare sollicitudin id et odio. Etiam fermentum pharetra orci, in posuere nisi condimentum at. Sed mattis accumsan convallis. Ut commodo posuere laoreet. Curabitur iaculis vestibulum arcu, vel egestas nibh tristique semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris consequat dui non sapien consequat euismod. Nulla facilisi. Etiam venenatis ligula id risus auctor eu faucibus est adipiscing. Quisque elit justo, vehicula sed dapibus nec, viverra ultrices est. Nunc vel orci eu dui vehicula vehicula tincidunt sagittis dui.

Etiam odio ipsum, feugiat vel vulputate ac, eleifend ut lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus tellus ante, scelerisque sed sollicitudin vitae, semper in mauris. Curabitur non elit risus. Nam vitae facilisis enim. Nam pulvinar, eros at fringilla molestie, nisi diam ultricies diam, consectetur facilisis mi felis vitae lectus. Mauris augue sem, rhoncus sit amet varius at, venenatis at dolor. Quisque pharetra, erat at blandit venenatis, massa urna eleifend felis, in luctus tortor ligula nec urna. Nam aliquam blandit justo, eu ornare leo luctus a. Proin id volutpat augue. Praesent mollis tempor mi et congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
</div></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the text should scroll on clicking of next and prev buttons?

Comment: @vitorino yes the text should scroll on clicking of next and prev buttons like the image http://imgur.com/eW3ggwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to keep fixed the box or the box-text? If it is the entire box you can't achieve fixed width or height using %. You should express it in px. If you need to use % then you can add a script that replaces width and height properties once the html is loaded

```
<script>
    var boxWidth = document.getElementById('myId').offsetWidth;
    var boxHeight = document.getElementById('myId').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById('myId').style.width = boxWidth + "px";
    document.getElementById('myId').style.height = boxHeight + "px";
</script>
```

Remember to assign 'myId' to your box div

Comment: thanks for share but what I'm looking for is to create a text box same as the image http://imgur.com/eW3ggwt no matter the element what is it, scrollbar or carousel or anything equivalent

Comment: If you know the size of your box, just change the width:50% and height:50% with for example... width:300px and height: 500px that will make it size fixed

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm using % to keep the box responsive rather then fixed px depends on the device used not the text. What I want exactly is something like the picture shows: http://imgur.com/eW3ggwt. It might not be called a scrolling box but what is the name and how can it be done? Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you want to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/86udouqg/ this is your code in action as it is now, and I don't see what do you want to change.

Comment: here is the code running http://jsfiddle.net/a9chg5t2/ what it misses is the scrolling. Compare it to the image and check out the next/previous button http://imgur.com/eW3ggwt

Comment: The code you provided in the question is different from the one you linked me now, especially because of the display: overflow; property in your box class. http://jsfiddle.net/a9chg5t2/1/

Comment: I do apologize for any inconvenience or misunderstanding and second I much appreciate your support. I know abou the overflow I already added however I don't need standard one. What I'm looking for is a scrollbar aligned left and text right and scrollbar which is about arrows up/down with out the middle bar hope you got what I mean. Only 2 arrows without the bar itself and scrolls up and down that's it. Thank you again and again

Answer (score -1):

A simple example for an overflow box: http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/v5kumrah/

Using the "overlay" value:

```
.box-text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 210px;
    overflow: overlay;
}
```

Comment: @2633390 thanks for share but what I'm looking for is to create a text box same as the image http://imgur.com/eW3ggwt no matter the element what is it, scrollbar or carousel or anything equivalent